# How can i create a setting page (alike general setting) in odoo- witj Many2one relation

Tags: python, configuration, settings, odoo-12

I want to create a page look like general setting page in odoo and i have found that I have to use TransientModel class but I have so many fields with many2one relation that is forbidden with TransientModel

I have used TransientModel class but i got error because I used Many2one relation in my code

```
<record id="your_configuration" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Your configuration</field>
    <field name="model">matab.settingtag</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Your configuration" class="oe_form_configuration">
            <header>
                <button string="Save" type="object"
                    name="execute" class="oe_highlight"/>
                or
                <button string="Cancel" type="object"
                    name="cancel" class="oe_link"/>
            </header>
            <group string="Company">
            <!--<label for="id" string="Name &amp; Phone"/>-->
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <field name="active_units"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <field name="doctor_working_hour_time_control"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </group>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

I want a setting page that open directly and save correctly look like general setting in odoo- i have to use many2one relation in my modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Way Odoo 12 handles this is to create the fields on the company_id, then create a related field in the settings.

```
class ResCompany(models.Model)
    _inherit = 'res.company'

   many2one_field = fields.Many2one('related.model', 'Field Name')
   #Edit for non many2one field setting
   related_default_value_duration = fields.Float(string='Duration', default=0.25)

   @api.model
def get_values(self):
    res = super(ResConfigSettings, self).get_values()
    res['related_default_value_duration'] = float(self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('settingtag.related_default_value_duration', default=0.25))
    return res

@api.model
def set_values(self):
    self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().set_param('settingtag.related_default_value_duration', self.max_time)
    super(ResConfigSettings, self).set_values()      



class ResConfigSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'

    many2one_field = fields.Many2one('related.model', 'Field Name', related='company_id.many2one_field')
```

Then you should be able to add it to your settings view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
  <!-- Add in configuration items -->
  <record id="res_config_view_name_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.config.view.name.form</field>
    <field name="model">res.config.settings</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.res_config_settings_view_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('settings')]" position="inside">
        <div class="app_settings_block" data-string="Module Name" string="Module Name" data-key="module_name" groups="">
          <h2>Title of Group of Settings</h2>
          <div class="row mt16 o_settings_container">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-12 o_setting_box">
              <div class="o_setting_right_pane">
                <span class="o_form_label">Field Name</span>
                <div>
                <field name="many2one_field " class="oe_inline"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </xpath>
    </field>
  </record>
</odoo>
```

Please note that "module_name" needs to be the name of the directory (same as in an external id for a view)

*****IMPORTANT*****

Please note that if you are running in Multi Company these fields will need to be set for each company individually.

Comment: what is the related.model? is it res.company?

Comment: No, so if the field is `user_id` then the related.model would be `res.users`.

Comment: and i want to notice that in my setting modules there is not any many2one but other fields in other models have many2one relation with some fields in setting module, what is my solution?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand.  The above method is just for Many2one references, unless you want to have settings be different between companies.  On another note, I forgot to put in the field definition with `related=` you need to have `, readonly=False`.

Comment: i have a model setting that i want to show fields on this in setting page a like general setting page, here is my setting model: class SettingTag(models.Model):
    _name = 'matab.settingtag'

    active_units = fields.Boolean(string="Active Units")
    unit_time_control = fields.Boolean(string="Active Unit's Time Control")

    related_default_value_duration = fields.Float(string='Duration', default=00.25)
    default_value_duration = fields.Float(string='Duration', default=00.25)
    imits=fields.Many2many(relation='relation1',comodel_name='specialtylist',string="Medical Specialty")

Comment: but Odoo Raise Error because a field in Another Model has Many2one Relation with this field : "related_default_value_duration" that i have mentioned in previous comment, how can i fixed this error? @CristinMeravi

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer for setting the config settings.  To retrieve information from the config settings you would do `settings = self.env['res.config.settings'].get_values()` which returns a dictionary of the settings, then you use `settings['related_default_value_duration ']` to get your value.  If you have a many2one relationship as a setting, remember that it is set on the company_id so you would have to use the calling models `company_id.many2one_field` or if you want the current company that the user is logged into you can use `self.env.user.company_id.many2one_field`